# Вызов функции asyncio

Tags: python, функции, aiogram, asyncio

```
async def scheduler(time):
    aioschedule.every().day.at(time_str=time).do(load_qwes)
    print('Метка вызова времени')
    while True:
        await aioschedule.run_pending()
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def on_startup(dp):
    asyncio.create_task(scheduler('12:00'))
    asyncio.create_task(scheduler('20:00'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp,on_startup=on_startup)
```

`asyncio.create_task(scheduler('17:33'))` вызывает функцию по `scheduler` 2 раза.
Как переделать, чтоб вызывал по одному разу.

Comment: while True вынесите в функцию on_startup. Цикл обработки должен быть один.

Comment: Не помогло, ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Получилось, только еще через один цикл в функции scheduler

Comment: Только теперь команды хэндлеров теперь не работают)

Comment: По идее вот так должно работать: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7LSW.png